# Alternative for getStaticProps in Next.js 13.2 with Sanity

Tags: next.js, sanity

Basically the title.

I'm currently trying to learn Sanity and on their website (https://www.sanity.io/docs/connect-your-content-to-next-js) they use `getStaticProps`. However, I'm using the experimental app directory in Next.js 13.2 and `getStaticProps` is not allowed, only other data fetching methods. I've tried my hand at a few different options and this option doesn't present me with any errors in my console, however, it's not working either. What am I missing?

TIA

Here's my code:

```
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";

export default async function Home() {
  const chinaData = await getPhotos();

  console.log(chinaData);

  return <main>...</main>;
}

const client = createClient({
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET,
  apiVersion: "2023-03-17",
  useCdn: false,
});

async function getPhotos() {
  const query = `*[_type == "china"]{
    alternative_text,
    caption,
    date,
    description_long,
    description_short,
    hashtags,
    location,
    photo
  }
  `;

  const chinaData = await client.fetch(query);
  console.log(chinaData);

  return {
    props: {
      chinaData,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add the link (maybe http://localhost:3000) to the API tap in sanity account to whitelist it, and then check the network tap if there is any errors